# Why does Prisma generate an unique index instead of a unique column constraint based on "unique" on the scheme?

Tags: sql, sqlite, prisma

I know that a "unique index" is equivalent to a UNIQUE column constraint, but wouldn't that be clearer when reading the raw SQL, and avoid confusion with indexes which are created for pure performance reasons?

Here's an example schema, taken directly from Prisma's Quickstart docs:

```
// This is your Prisma schema file,
// learn more about it in the docs: https://pris.ly/d/prisma-schema

generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
  provider = "sqlite"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

model User {
  id    Int     @id @default(autoincrement()) 
  email String  @unique
  name  String?
  posts Post[]
}

model Post {
  id        Int     @id @default(autoincrement())
  title     String
  content   String?
  published Boolean @default(false) 
  author    User    @relation(fields: [authorId], references: [id])
  authorId  Int
}
```

Note how the "email" unique declaration gets actualized in an unique index at the end of the schema (SQLite):

```sql
SELECT sql FROM sqlite_schema;
CREATE TABLE "_prisma_migrations" (
    "id"                    TEXT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    "checksum"              TEXT NOT NULL,
    "finished_at"           DATETIME,
    "migration_name"        TEXT NOT NULL,
    "logs"                  TEXT,
    "rolled_back_at"        DATETIME,
    "started_at"            DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp,
    "applied_steps_count"   INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
)

CREATE TABLE "User" (
    "id" INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    "email" TEXT NOT NULL,
    "name" TEXT
)
CREATE TABLE sqlite_sequence(name,seq)
CREATE TABLE "Post" (
    "id" INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    "title" TEXT NOT NULL,
    "content" TEXT,
    "published" BOOLEAN NOT NULL DEFAULT false,
    "authorId" INTEGER NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT "Post_authorId_fkey" FOREIGN KEY ("authorId") REFERENCES "User" ("id") ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE
)
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "User_email_key" ON "User"("email")
```

I tried to guess what could be the reason. My best guess is that Prisma's internal logic prefers to have as many things as possible as indexes, but maybe there's another reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short it doesn't really matter as the end result is effectively the same.

i.e. an index, just that the specifically named index rather than generated named index may be less confusing. There may also be a  factor in that the name is easily determined/already named should it subsequently be utilised.

- the specifically named being when `CREATE INDEX ....` is used
- the generated named being an INDEX that is automatically created

Consider this extract from

**3.6 UNIQUE constraints**

> A UNIQUE constraint is similar to a PRIMARY KEY constraint, except that a single table may have any number of UNIQUE constraints. For each UNIQUE constraint on the table, each row must contain a unique combination of values in the columns identified by the UNIQUE constraint. For the purposes of UNIQUE constraints, NULL values are considered distinct from all other values, including other NULLs. As with PRIMARY KEYs, a UNIQUE table-constraint clause must contain only column names — the use of expressions in an indexed-column of a UNIQUE table-constraint is not supported.

> ***In most cases, UNIQUE*** and PRIMARY KEY ***constraints are implemented by creating a unique index in the database.*** (The exceptions are INTEGER PRIMARY KEY and PRIMARY KEYs on WITHOUT ROWID tables.) Hence, the following schemas are logically equivalent:

```
CREATE TABLE t1(a, b UNIQUE);
CREATE TABLE t1(a, b PRIMARY KEY);
CREATE TABLE t1(a, b);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX t1b ON t1(b);
```

- https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#unique_constraints

i.e. `CREATE TABLE t1(a, b UNIQUE);` and `CREATE UNIQUE INDEX t1b ON t1(b);`  are functionally the same other than the name of the first index is system generated whilst the second is named according to the given name.

**Demonstration**

Consider the following that uses both ways and then outputs the schema:-

```
CREATE TABLE User1 (
    id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    email TEXT NOT NULL,
    name TEXT
);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX User_email_key ON User1(email);
CREATE TABLE User2 (
    id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    email TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    name TEXT
);
SELECT * FROM sqlite_master;
```

Which results in :-

[image]

As you can see the generated index has been created and named according to SQLite naming conventions.

- unlikely to be of use, there is also no associated SQL as it has been generated automatically.